# Is there anyway to limit the number of QueryParam?

Tags: java, rest

I have an API that has a POST with 2 query params.

The thing is, that I want to limit the user to only 1 of them.

i.e.

```
@Post 
    public Response postIt(@QueryParam("item1") String item1, @QueryParam("item2") String item2) {
.....
}
```

is there any way to limit the user to send only 1 of them without validating it inside the method?
so that it will throw an error if both item1 and item2 were sent.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with validating it inside the method? A simple if will suffice.

Comment: You just try to overwhelm the implementations I think, you need to take in class and write a custom annotation for that.